# Xamarin forms PCL floating buttons and expandable view

Tags: android, ios, button, xamarin.forms, floating

How could implement something similar to the following link in Xamarin Forms?

```
[https://codepen.io/SoufianeLasri/pen/BobJzG][1]
```

[On clicked it zoom the view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/doXIX.png)

[image: A carrousel of buttons]

Comment: You can use the [Syncfusion Radial Menu Control for Xamarin.Forms](https://www.syncfusion.com/products/xamarin/radial-menu) to archive the first behavior, and the second one looks like you need an horizontal listview, check [this tutorial](https://causerexception.com/2018/02/06/xamarin-forms-ultimate-horizontal-list-guide/)